# How to display title of page in body content under h1 tag

Tags: php, joomla

i have used RSSEO plugin for optimizing my joomla site, however i want my h1 tag in custom components and pages to be similar to page title. Tried below

```
 <h1>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 document.write(document.title);
  //-->
  </script></h1>
```

The above script is able to display h1 tag, but when checks source code its not seo friendly as display script

I think i need server side php code, have tried using

```
  <h1><?php echo $PageTitle ?></h1>
```

But above is not displaying any value. only leading to blank h1 tags

Can anyone suggest and advise pls to do it effectively

thanks

Comment: Do you know what variable has the page title, and if its available in the context you are trying to use it?

Comment: have you defined $PageTitle anywhere? php can't magically populate a variable for you just because the variable's name is vaguely related to something in an html page - php knows nothing of webpages or html. it just sees text.

Comment: So you are placing variable values into the `<title>` tag but don't know how to do the same for the `<h1>`?

Comment: Hello, i have checked on database, there its showing that <pagetitle> is the field which stores all headings of all the urls. the table name is fun_rsdetails . pl advise am i missing any detail and then how to get it worked up in a code to display the title as h1 tag

Comment: Where do you want to add the code? In a template? In a template override for articles...

Comment: @cppl - it will be in articles

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<h1 id="pagetitle"></h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = document.title;
```

If you want the script inline:

```
<h1 id="pagetitle"></h1>
<script>
    document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = document.title;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <?php
    $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $page = fread(fopen($url, "r"), 2048);   // first 2KB


    if(preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i",$page,$result))
       {
           echo "The title of $url is $result[1]</b>";
       }
      else
     {
                   echo "The page doesn't have a title tag";
       }

?>
```

This will load faster as you want :

Comment: The OP is using Joomla! there is no file, you would effectively be getting the CMS to render the page in turn, to get the title, which would in turn get the page again ad infinitum…

Comment: @Zan Your solution works perfectly. **However, to surprise, the loading time of the page jumps 7 times** . When i reverted back to original h1 which was there, it again become normal. The page wait time is 1.01 s which after implementing above went upto 7.26 s. Why so?

Comment: Because it is getting the page content , to know the title content

Comment: if it increases loading time by that much, then this code is not a fit as a solution

Comment: Hello Zan, its much better than the previous scenario, however server look time is still high.. I tried reducing to it to 1kb, but still its taking thrice the time

Comment: when you get the answer PM me , m too interested in knowning best approach

Answer (score 0):

Joomla $document will contain the title, so simply inject it in your component / template:

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
echo "<h1>".$document->getMetaData('title')."</h1>";
?>
```

this should do the trick.

Comment: No Riccardo, its leaving a blank .. Pl advise, the page titles are stored in table car_rsform_pages and structure as pagetitle as the field name. how to achieve it. thnx

Answer (score 0):

This works in Joomla! 2.5.x:

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
?>
<h1><?php echo $document->getTitle(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: Hi pshentsoff, it works but been my seo of site taken up by a plugin of rs joomla, hence above is not displaying the modified title... is there any way to call up title from database table fun_rsdetails which stores all seo and title are stored as pagetitle in it as field